# Missing entries in user.config after decryption/encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-5

I like to store a username and password to the user.config in my C# .net5 program. I don't want to store the password direct and I decided to decrypt the userSettings section.
After decryption parts of the file are missing.

Orginal user.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" >
            <section name="FileUploader.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <FileUploader.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>user</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
                <value>xyz</value>
            </setting>
        </FileUploader.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

After encryption:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" >
            <section name="FileUploader.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <FileUploader.Properties.Settings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
            <EncryptedData>
                <CipherData>
                    <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
            </EncryptedData>
        </FileUploader.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

After decryption:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" >
            <section name="FileUploader.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <FileUploader.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="" serializeAs="String">
                <value>xyz</value>
            </setting>
        </FileUploader.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

There is only the last entry and the name of the entry is missing. If I switch the order in the original file, I get "user" as the value.

The code to decrypt/encrypt (more or less a copy of an msdn example):

```
private void ProtectSettings()
{ 
    // Get the application configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
            ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

    // Define the Rsa provider name.
    string provider = "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider";

    string section = "userSettings/" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".Properties.Settings";

    // Get the section to protect.
    ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.GetSection(section);

    if (connStrings != null)
    {
        if (!connStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            if (!connStrings.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
            {
                // Protect the section.
                connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);

                connStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                        
                Debug.WriteLine("Section {0} is now protected by {1}",
                    connStrings.SectionInformation.Name,
                    connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectionProvider.Name);
            }
            else
                Debug.WriteLine(
                        "Can't protect, section {0} is locked",
                        connStrings.SectionInformation.Name);
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine(
                "Section {0} is already protected by {1}",
                connStrings.SectionInformation.Name,
                connStrings.SectionInformation.ProtectionProvider.Name);
    }
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("Can't get the section {0}", section);
}

private static void UnProtectSettings()
{
    // Get the application configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
            ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

    string section = "userSettings/" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ".Properties.Settings";

    // Get the section to unprotect.
    ConfigurationSection connStrings = config.GetSection(section);

    if (connStrings != null)
    {
        if (connStrings.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            if (!connStrings.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
            {
                // Unprotect the section.
                connStrings.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();

                connStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                        
                Debug.WriteLine("Section {0} is now unprotected.",
                    connStrings.SectionInformation.Name);
            }
            else
                Debug.WriteLine(
                        "Can't unprotect, section {0} is locked",
                        connStrings.SectionInformation.Name);
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine(
                "Section {0} is already unprotected.",
                connStrings.SectionInformation.Name);
    }
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("Can't get the section {0}", section);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with this for a while, I discovered that the issue comes from the `ConfigurationSaveMode.Full` option.

In both `ProtectSettings()` and `UnProtectSettings()`, instead of

```cs
connStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

simply use:

```cs
config.Save();
```

I have no idea why that option leads to unwanted behavior.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect after switching the lines. Should I hand this in as a bug report für .NET5?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62233